# How can I get my broadcom wifi card to work?

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

I have a BCM43142:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0611]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at b0400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

And I can only get wifi networks to show up with the `wl` driver, from `bcmwl-kernel-source`. I blacklisted the other drivers as necessary. When using `wl`, my connection is often five or six times slower than on Windows, and usually cuts out after about a minute or so. I can reconnect to the network, but then it cuts out again after about a minute. How can I get it to work reliably?

Everything works fine on Windows with this wifi card, and other devices on the network work fine.

I should mention that I'm running 14.10 with all the latest updates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 3):

I believe that one or more drivers that require blacklisting are still loading. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist b43"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist bcma"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist brcmsmac"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist ssb"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot and run again:

```
lspci -v
```

We hope we see the driver in use is only wl and not bcma, bcma-pci-bridge, etc. and that your wireless works as expected.

Comment: yes. bcma-pci-bridge should not be the module in use but wl. I already have a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf here. I wonder if it's bcmwl-kernel-source that created it or not

Comment: The lspci output in my question showed bcma-pci-bridge instead of wl, since I was trying that driver at the time. But my main problem is that when I'm using wl, and only wl, then my wifi cuts out every minute or so. I blacklisted all the other drivers like you suggest, but the problem is not loading the driver, the problem is that the driver, when properly loaded, isn't working well--my wifi keeps cutting out every minute, and is excruciatingly slow. I'll edit my question to reflect my current lscpi output.

Comment: this is the "official" driver for this hardware. Look in /var/log/syslog to see for NetworkManager log (if you use it) to see if it's not the router's fault that disconnect you

Comment: You might post: dmesg | grep -e wlan -e wl Thanks.